# MvvmCross 4.4 Click binding not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi Xamarin/MvvmCross devs,

After a recent update to my Android project the command bindings of all my buttons has stopped working.

**The project updates are as follows:**

- MvvmCross (multiple libs): 4.3.0 -> 4.4.0
- **MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Core.Utils + MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4: 4.3.0 -> 4.3.1**
- MonoFramework: 6.0 -> 7.0.
- Xamarin.Android.Support (multiple libs): 23.4.0.1 -> 24.2.1

The bold item in the list bothers me a bit, can it be that? The command binding to ItemClick for RecycleViews/ListViews still work, <s>as well as the Click bindings to normal views (Custom LinearLayouts, Views etc).</s> But none of the bindings to Click work.

**Things I've tried:**

- I checked the LinkerPleaseInclude.cs and it has the "Original" bindings in it, nothing has changed there.
- When I bind to the Click command manually from the "Code behind" and fire the command manually it still works (so I can do that for every button I have in the app as a workaround, not preferred)

**Some information that might be relevant:**

The app has one activity (MvxAppCompatActivity) and hosts multiple MvxFragments. The buttons are bound from xaml as follows:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="SEARCH"
    android:textSize="@dimen/search_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    local:MvxBind="Click SearchCommand" />
```

When the manual binding to the Click command is not done the FABs don't elevate when it gets touched. Manual meaning bound in code behind the view as below:

```
button.Click += OnButtonClicked;
```

I will resort to binding like above for all buttons, but any feedback would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** Command binding to Click does not work on the other views, just on the ItemClick binding for ListView/RecyclerView.

**UPDATE 2:** All bindings are only going one way. When RaisePropertyChanged is called the property is updated. But binding to a EditText view and typing in it, does not fire the property setter.

**UPDATE 3:** After all the searching I'm giving up due to time constraints. I have reverted everything back to the packages as indicated above. The bindings work fine again.

Comment: Try to clean your app solution and run again.

Comment: How do you inflate your views in your fragments?

Comment: @idenardi I've done that multiple times throughout the mission of trying to figure out what's wrong. It doesn't change anything

Comment: @Cheesebaron I use BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.ViewId, null) and then I use Cheeseknife to retrieve individual views.

Comment: Make a minimal reproducible sample and file an issue on GitHub if you believe it is a bug.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Will do when I get some time :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: I had a similar issue when clicking on a button, the binding did not work.  When the button was clicked (I was using a command instead of a click event) I had to force the focus to change to get the binding to work.